# How to get url parameter and add active class witt javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My links are like that:

```
index.php
index.php?do=that
index.php?do=this
```

And my current javascript code is like that:

```
var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
    console.log(url);
    $('.nav-link').each(function(){
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

So with this code even if I'm at `index.php?do=this` console log says to me `/path/index.php`

I think I need make changes on `var url = window.location.pathname` line but I couldn't.

How should I improve my code? There are bunch of similiar questions here in SO, but not the same one.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: use url.split("/")

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can get your URL parameters from GET array.
$_GET['do'] or try to print $_GET. This array will print all the URL parameters.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but I wanna success it only with javascript.

Comment: Why don't you try "Windows.location.href" instead of pathname?